# How to override environment variables with .tfvars in provider config for Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am implementing the Checkpoint terraform provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/CheckPointSW/checkpoint/latest/docs

The provider will consume environment variables in place of explicitly declared variables in the provider definition (i.e. `CHECKPOINT_USERNAME`, `CHECKPOINT_PASSWORD`).

I would like to keep this behavior, but in my dev environment I would also like to provide a `.tfvars` file to specify these settings. Essentially, I want to consume the default environment variables, or override them with a `.tfvars`.

But, I realize that the provider is looking explicitly for the `CHECKPOINT_USERNAME` environment variable and Terraform would be looking for something like `TFVARS_CHECKPOINT_USERNAME` which could then be overridden in a `.tfvars` with `CHECKPOINT_USERNAME = "test"`.

**How do I implement this so that `.tfvars` overrides the `CHECKPOINT_xxx` environment variables within the provider definition?**

I considered trying to set a `default = <environment variable>` in the variables definition, but `default` requires a literal value.

Comment: This is 100% doable, I do this all the time... the values in .tfvars overrides the values from environment variables  ... are you running into any errors?

Comment: Should point out that `TFVARS_CHECKPOINT_USERNAME` is incorrect, from the documentation it should be `TF_VAR_...`  https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

`.tfvars` files are for passing values to the input variables of the root module. Terraform Core does not pass them directly to providers, but you can in principle use root module input variables to *indirectly* populate provider configuration arguments:

```
variable "checkpoint_username" {
  type = string
}

provider "checkpoint" {
  username = var.checkpoint_username
  # ...
}
```

Note that input variables are a *planning option* in Terraform's model, so they get fixed as part of the plan and Terraform will always use the same values during apply.

This is not a big concern if you are just running `terraform apply` at the command line to plan and apply in quick succession, but this use of input variables for authentication-related settings is often not appropriate for production environments because there might be some delay between the plan phase and the apply phase where credentials need to change or be renewed. Environment variables don't have this problem because they *can* readily change between the plan phase and the apply phase, as long as they still refer to a user with permissions consistent with those used to create the original plan. (This may not be a concern for the specific provider we're discussing here since it doesn't seem like the underlying platform supports time-limited sessions anyway, but I mention it just in case someone who sees this answer tries to adapt it for another provider.)